# Passing runtime data from a component to a HoC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component like the following:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
    // hook specific to the component
    const { data, loading, error } = useGetDashboardDataQuery();

    // rendering that I would like to extract into a HOC
    if (loading) return <Loader />;
    if (error) return <Error />;

    // rendering specific to the component
    if (data) {
        return <h2>{data.dashboard_title}</h2>;
    }

    return null;
};
```

I would like for my loading/error handling to not be specific to this particular component, so I can reuse it with other components.

So my initial idea was to use a HOC (higher-order-component). However, the HOC has no concept of my `useGetDashboardDataQuery`, and I cannot pass them in because the HOC is handled at compile time, ex:

```js
class Dashboard = () => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useGetDashboardDataQuery();
    ...
}

export default withLoader(Dashboard); // cannot pass loading/error here
```

From reading the documentation, it is suggested to [lift up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). But since my `useGetDashboardDataQuery` hook is specific to the component, I'm not sure how to do this in an abstract way.

Another suggestion I was given was to use [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) but I am having a hard time applying it to this use case.

I come from a PHP background so still learning to do these things in an idiomatic functional react way. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: what is `useGetDashboardDataQuery`? custom fetching / react-query / apollo?

Comment: @szaman yep, it's an automatically generated hook. by graphql-codegen (using config option withMutation: true)

Comment: in this case, don't use `loading`. it reflects the current network status and not whether the data is available. for example, if your component is initially rendered, and then an update is made which refetches the query, your app will show a loading spinner instead of displaying slightly outdated data for a moment. use `!data`, `_.isNil(data)` (from lodash) or `data == null` (sic) instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it later. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a condtional wrapper component which takes `data`, `error` and `loading` as props in some form. It will check these values and return the children if data should be displayed.

This is how you would use it in any component:

```
return (
  <LoaderHandler data={data} error={error} loading={loading}>
    <h2>{data?.dashboard_title}</h2> 
  </LoaderHandler>
);
```

And the wrapper would look something like this:

```
// i don't know what library (if any) you're using to fetch data,
// so not sure about the correct types here.
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
  data: ?;
  error?: ?; 
  loading: boolean;
};

const LoaderHandler = ({children, data, error, loading}: Props): JSX.Element | null => {
  if (loading) return <Loader />;
  if (error) return <Error />;
  if (!data) return null;
  return children;
};
```

One caveat: typescript will complain if you try to use `data.dashboard_title` because `data` might be undefined or null. You can replace it with `data?.dashboard_title` or, because your wrapper already checks for it and makes sure data will not be undefined or null, `data!.dashboard_title`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks so obvious in hindsight.

Comment: I'm still getting an error with this approach, as the child components are mounted prior to the parent. So the initial render will fail (as data does not exist yet).

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dashboard_title')"

I think it's because child components are mounted first, there is no "if (data)" check in the Dashboard component. When I add an additional check, it does work. But it means I'm duplicating some code.

Comment: like i mentioned in my answer, you should use `data?.dashboard_title` which will check whether `data` is undefined.

Comment: I followed "because your wrapper already checks for it and makes sure data will not be undefined or null, data!.dashboard_title.", which did make sense to me. But it won't work because if order of mounting, I guess.